# East-growing tree does not fit in tikzpicture

Tags: forest

This code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
We are the knights who say "Ni!".
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
    \begin{forest}
        [,for tree={grow'=east},shape=coordinate
            [
                [
                    []
                    []
                ]
                [
                    []
                    []
                ]
            ]
            [
                [
                    []
                    []
                ]
                [
                    []
                    []
                ]
            ]
        ]
        \end{forest}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

gives me

[image: Results of above code]

Clearly, the tree gets out of the bounds of the picture, which makes it overlap the text above. Is this a known bug or a blunder on my part, and is there a fix ?

Comment: Don't put a `forest` in a `tikzpicture`. I'm pretty sure this is just not going to work. Actually, I'm surprised you get anything at all, to be honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is at all a good idea to put a `forest` environment inside a `tikzpicture` and I strongly suspect that Bad Things may happen unexpectedly. In general, nesting `tikzpicture`s sometimes works in simple cases but is known to be problematic. (That is, if it works, it works. If it doesn't, you get to keep both pieces.) Remember that a `forest` is a `tikzpicture` so you are essentially saying

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
  ...
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    ...
```

For your example, it does work if you adjust the `baseline` of the picture appropriately.

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[framed,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
```

I think it would be safer, however, to draw the frame as part of the `forest`. I take it you want, eventually, to have something fancier than a mere box. If not, there are simpler approaches. But a complex background can be added easily as part of the `forest` specification itself. There are several ways of doing this.

```
\begin{forest}
  [
    ..
  ]
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    <drawing commands>
  \end{scope}
\end{forest}
```

Or the drawing commands can be added as part of the tree specification or in the tree preamble. For example,

```
  \begin{forest}
    [,for tree={grow'=east},shape=coordinate, tikz+={%
      \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node [fit=(current bounding box.north east) (current bounding box.south west), draw=blue!50!cyan, outer color=blue!50!cyan!25, inner color=blue!50!cyan!10, rounded corners, line width=1mm] {};
      \end{scope}
    }
        [
    ...
  \end{forest}
```

[image: boxed trees]

Complete code for examples:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit}

\begin{document}
We are the knights who say "Ni!".
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[framed,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \begin{forest}
      [,for tree={grow'=east},shape=coordinate
          [
              [
                  []
                  []
              ]
              [
                  []
                  []
              ]
          ]
          [
              [
                  []
                  []
              ]
              [
                  []
                  []
              ]
          ]
      ]
    \end{forest}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
We are the knights who say "Ni!".
\begin{center}
  \begin{forest}
    [,for tree={grow'=east},shape=coordinate, tikz+={%
      \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node [fit=(current bounding box.north east) (current bounding box.south west), draw=blue!50!cyan, outer color=blue!50!cyan!25, inner color=blue!50!cyan!10, rounded corners, line width=1mm] {};
      \end{scope}
    }
        [
            [
                []
                []
            ]
            [
                []
                []
            ]
        ]
        [
            [
                []
                []
            ]
            [
                []
                []
            ]
        ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Whoops, I had overlooked that `forest` was already a `tikzpicture`. I actually didn't need the frame, it was just a mean of highlighting the bounding box. Thanks for the details, though!